# How do I get an Array(Number) from Firestore in Android

Tags: java, android

I am wanting to get an array(number) from firestore and then use that arrays contents(example[0], etc...).
The reason for doing so is that im trying to use the contents to populate a line graph with it and though that this may be the best solution, however I am open to suggestions if you think there would be a better way.
I have been unable to find a solution to this problem.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm getting you right then your problem can be resolved by the way below.
fetch that content in ArrayList and run forloop.

in kotlin

```
for(number in arrayList){
//number is item for each time loop is execute till arrayList.size
}
```

in java

```
for(int i=0;i<arrayList.size,i++){
 arryList.get(i)
}
```

to get arrayList from firestore

```
  private val fireStore: FirebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
    val arrayList:ArrayList<Users> =ArrayList()
            fireStore.collection("COLLECTION_NAME")
                    .get()
                    .addOnSuccessListener { snapshot->
                        for(document in snapshot){
                            val userData=document.toObject(Users::class.java)
                            userData.userId=document.id
                            arrayList.add(userData)
                        }
                    }
                    .addOnFailureListener { exception->
                        Toast.makeText(fragment.context, exception.message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }
```

User above is a model class you can made of your own kind. this code is in kotlin if you need java version then please visit the official documentation. link is below and do know me if you still got problems.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data

Comment: I'm wanting to do that afterwards so my problem is with getting that arrayList from Firestore

Comment: With my double's I simply use data.get("weight") but how do I get an array ?

Comment: visit the answer and do know me again.